# Prompt не корректно работает с условными операторами

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, вопрос по JS. В коде необходимо чтобы при вводе в всплывающем меню одного слова открывала одна страница, при вводе другого другая страница. Первая страница открывается всегда, вне зависимости от того какое слово введешь.

```
function open_podtvergdenie() {
   prompt('Какую страницу вы хотите открыть("Интернет вещей" или его "Применение")', 'Интернет вещей');
   var p=prompt;
   if (p="Интернет вещей"){
     document.location.href=str1;
   } else  {
     document.location.href=str2;
   }
}
```

PS. str1 и str 2 в глобальных переменных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во-первых, во второй строке в переменную `p` вы присваиваете код функции `prompt`, а не результат её выполнения в первой строке, во-вторых в `if` в `p` вы присваиваете значение, а не сравниваете

```js
function open_podtvergdenie() {
  var p = prompt('Какую страницу вы хотите открыть("Интернет вещей" или его "Применение")', 'Интернет вещей');
  if (p == "Интернет вещей") {
    console.log(1);
  } else {
    console.log(2);
  }
}

open_podtvergdenie();
```

Comment: как правильно тогда присвоить результат выполнения?

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев так я же написал рабочий пример `var p = prompt('Какую страницу вы хотите открыть("Интернет вещей" или его "Применение")', 'Интернет вещей');`. Только замените вывод в консоль на `document.location.href`